# Is brownie supporting OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@5.0.0?

Tags: web3.py, openzeppelin, brownie

I got the following answer after runing
brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@5.0.0

WARNING: Unable to compile OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@5.0.0 due to a AttributeError - you may still be able to import sources from the package, but will be unable to load the package directly.